# Fixed salt generation based on input string - C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, salt

I have this simple class which has 2 methods:

```
private static byte[] PBKDF2(string field, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputBytes)

   {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(field, salt);
        pbkdf2.IterationCount = iterations;
        return pbkdf2.GetBytes(outputBytes);
    }

public static string CreateHash(string field, String salt)
    {
        //if (Array.TrueForAll(salt, x => x == 0))
        //{
        //    RNGCryptoServiceProvider csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        //    csprng.GetBytes(salt);
        //    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
        //}
        byte[] salts = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
        byte[] hash = PBKDF2(field, salts, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
```

I need to provide a front-end where user enters a simple string like "abc" and I need to generate a salt based on that. This is what I am going to store in the database and use it to pass to the above method (CreateHash) to de-identify 
data. This salt/key needs to be able to get decrypted back, which I have to show in the front-end.

I can use other classes/library as well. It need not be Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

Please provide me some inputs on how I can achieve this salt/key generation functionality. This salt can't be a random value.

Thanks!

Comment: Salts should be random and not based on user input. The entire point of a salt is if someone enters the same input twice you get two different outputs. If you are doing this because you need to "know the salt" when you go to verify the `byte[]` all you need to do is just prepend or append the salt to the front or back of the binary blob, when you go do verify you pull off the salt and feed it in to the PBKDF2 function.

Comment: Possible [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6a2836a-d587-4068-8630-94f4fb2a2aeb/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral) but it's using Rfc2898... Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I understand that salt is supposed to be dynamic but the requirement is different here. This is not for password storage. We need to de-identify dataand store them in files. Every time a file comes with some data, we encrypt and generate another file. All the personal information is de-identified. But for example for a given field say first name David, it always needs to be converted to the same encrypted to the same string as it generated earlier. It is not defined by me! If I fix the salt & pass to Rfc2898DeriveBytes to get the same string for the same input.

Comment: Then why use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and not just a simple hash?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain simple hash is not secure enough and also the final hash needs to be one way hash...in our case, salt can be decrypt-able but the final encrypted string is one way encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you need to decrypt the hashed string.

PBKDF2 is NOT an encryption algorithm, but a key derivation function, and you will not be able to calculate the original input from the resulting hash, with or without the salt.

What you should be looking for is encryption, not hashing.

Take a look at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as0w18af(v=vs.110).aspx) for some examples.